# Why does my function only return the first user's ID when looping through WordPress users?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How would I change the following function so that $user->ID would return all users ID's one at a time?

It now only returns the first user with lowest ID, and then adds that ID to all following users.
Resulting in that all users get the same categories as the first user.

user_kategoriat is an ACF field: here's what I've been looking at:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/

```php
add_filter( 'algolia_user_record', 'my_post_attributes', 10, 2 );

function my_post_attributes( $attributes ) {
    
    $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
        
    foreach ( $users as $user ) { 
                $ID = $user->ID;
        $attributes['kategoriat'] = get_field('user_kategoriat', 'user_'. $ID );
        return $attributes; 
    }
        
}
```

Comment: `return` exits the foreach loop AND the function entirely. You probably want to store the `$attributes` variable in an array you defined before the foreach loop, and return that array after the loop is over.

Comment: @ArthurBoucher Thanks, I kind of understand what you're saying but I don't know how to  execute this. Could you give an example?

Comment: This is what I could make out:

function my_post_attributes( array $attributes, $user ) {
 
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
$cats = array( get_field('user_kategoriat', 'user_'. $user->ID ) );

foreach ( $users as $user ) { 
 $user = $attributes['kategoriat'] = $cats; 
}
 return $attributes; 
}

It returns double brackets around the categories like so: "kategoriat": [
    [
      "Taide",
      "Media"
    ]
  ],

But don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

return exits the loop. You can try this:

```
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
$attributes = array();
    
foreach ( $users as $user ) { 
    $attributes['kategoriat'] = array(get_field('user_kategoriat', 'user_'. $user->ID ));
}
return $attributes;
```

Comment: Hi @MWD, for some reason your suggestion does not store the attributes. I'll add an answer with the code that worked for me and perhaps you can see what I was doing wrong to not get your suggestion to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked:

```
add_filter( 'algolia_user_record', 'my_post_attributes', 10, 2 );
function my_post_attributes( array $attributes, $user ) {

    $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
    $cats = array( get_field('user_kategoriat', 'user_'. $user->ID ) );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $user = $attributes['kategoriat'] = $cats;
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```